# Permission denied error in heroku django application

Tags: django, heroku

I got the error 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

while giving

```
git push heroku master
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you followed [these steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) ?

Comment: yes..I got correct output for heroku local web..

Comment: @Apu Check this https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to [Heroku dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account) and upload your ssh public key.

Comment: I don't have ssh public key.How can I take this ssh public key